# SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC,"score") in Sphinx does not work

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx, full-text-indexing

I try to sort the results of Sphinx Search by using SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC,"score") but it does not work (results are not sorted in descending order by "score" attribute).

My PHP code:

```
$sphinx = new SphinxClient;
$sphinx->SetServer('localhost', 9312);
$sphinx->SetConnectTimeout(1);
$sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC,"score");
$sphinx->AddQuery('@attribute1="^test$"' , 'IndexName'); 
$result = $sphinx->RunQueries();
```

my configuration file

```
source SourceName
{
type            = mysql
sql_host        = localhost
sql_user        = root
sql_pass        = ******
sql_db          = DBName
sql_query_pre   = SET NAMES utf8
sql_port        = 3306

sql_query       =   SELECT * FROM TableName
sql_attr_uint       = score
}

index IndexName
{
source          = SourceName
path            = C:/sphinx/data/SourceName
min_word_len = 1
charset_table = a..z, _,.....
}
```

Comment: how exactly are you looking at the order of results? Could something else be giving you them in a different order to what sphinx returns them?

Comment: Thank you ! in fact the SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_ATTR_DESC,"score") works well ! the problem is due to the SQL query when I want  to select all table attributes from database by using the IDs (primary keys) returned by Sphinx Search, so these IDs are sorted  as I wanted but the SQL query "always" returns the results sorted in ascending order by primary key (id). I would have liked to make use of the sorted IDs by Sphinx without using the "ORDER BY" in SQL query to optimize the time of this query.

Comment: There is a trick with the FIELD() function, to get mysql to return the rows in the same order as sphinx provided the ids: http://sphinxsearch.com/info/faq/#row-storage - but its probably not going to be much more efficent that using `ORDER BY score DESC` on the sql query. My favorite trick is to just store the results from mysql, and then loop though the ids, getting data from the stored array. This avoids anyone sorting (in app, and in mysql) demo: http://nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example2.phps (look at the display at the end. No sort phase!

Comment: Thank you very much ! this helps me !